# When is the integer width restricted?

Tags: c, integer, 64-bit, overflow, 32-bit

I was having trouble writing a program that asked the user for a value N and then outputted the result 5^N. The problem was that if the user inputted a number greater than (2^31)-1, their number would overflow and the program would give them an erroneous answer.

What I did was assign the integer value given by the user to an unsigned long integer value. This way if the program could check if a number greater than (2^31)-1 was inputted because the unsigned long can hold a much higher number of positive integers than signed int can. Doing this causes the program to function as it should because I can check whether or not overflow has occurred.

However my question is this: when the user inputs a value greater than 2^31 - 1 into the original signed integer variable (which should cause it to overflow), why is it that I can then assign this overflowed value into an unsigned and get what the "correct" number is? Does overflow only happen when attempting to do operations on that number? Does the memory store the actual number (unrestricted by bit width)?

```
 int endCount;
unsigned long endCountUn;  /* power N */

/* Read value of N */
printf("This program will compute 5^N; enter N: ");
scanf("%d", &endCount);

/*
User's value put into unsigned long. Helps with detecting overflow.
*/
endCountUn = endCount;

if ( (endCount < 0) && (endCountUn < 2147483648) )
{
    printf("The operation is undefined for negative integers\n");
}

else if ( endCountUn > 2147483647 )
{
    printf("The value exceeds the supported numerical range\n");
}
```

Comment: In C, integers do not "overflow". You can think of it as a modulo operation where the results of some operation always get treated with "modulo 2^(bits)". Just like an invisible part appended to the expression you wrote. Signed ints are usually represented in 2's complement. Your test in your first if basically tests if the upper - the sign bit of your number is 1 (which means negative if it is interpreted as a signed value). So all you need to understand what is going on is to look up how 2's complement works.

Comment: @user2225104: unsigned integers do not overflow; they wrap modulo 2^N where N is the number of bits.  On the other hand, when signed integers overflow, you trigger undefined behaviour and anything can happen (including the code appearing to work by wrapping from positive to negative).  Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `scanf()` is undefined when it is asked to process numbers too large to fit in the integer type.  If you enter a value larger than 2^31-1 in a 32-bit signed type, the result you get is undefined.  There's what usually happens, but formally, the behaviour is undefined.  (ISO 9899:2011 §7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function ¶10 says _'…or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
in the object, the behavior is undefined.'_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler All that "undefined" behavior is true. Only practically not relevant as in our world, in our universe, noone has written the "compiler from hell" yet. Noone generates extra assembly instructions just to make the point that "anything" can happen for those undefined use cases. So, for the purpose of explanation, it is good enough to assume that negative ints "underflow" to the largest positive integer, because you will not find a system which does not have 2's complement nor will you find the "compiler from hell" which does something else, just to prove your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( (endCount < 0) && (endCountUn < 2147483648) )
```

The block of this if is executed for numbers n which satisfy both conditions.
`endCount`, being a (32bit) signed integer, represented in 2's complement.
The first term of the expression thus selects all n where the upper bit is set:
Range1: [0x80000000...0xFFFFFFFF]
The second term selects all n which are in the range
Range2: [0x00000000..0x7FFFFFFF].
The set of n which are in both ranges is the empty set.
So, the body of your if above will never be executed.

The second if (else if part) asks for values in range 1.

So, your test code could be simplified to:

```
if( endCount < 0 ) { printf("Value out of range"); }
```

Because, no matter what the user enters (a negative or a value in Range 1), endCount will always be negative.

Finally, if you only want to allow unsigned integer values, why do you use `scanf("%d",endCount)` in the first place?
You could write instead:

```
uint32_t endCount = 0; // unsigned int is machine dependent...better use stdint.h...
...
scanf("%u", &endCount);
```

Output for a statement which would be intended to yield the second printf...

```
This program will compute 5^N; enter N: 2147483648
The value exceeds the supported numerical range
```

Output for a statement which would be intended to yield the first printf...

```
This program will compute 5^N; enter N: -10
The value exceeds the supported numerical range
```

Please look what this program outputs on your system for this...

```
uint32_t endCount;

/* Read value of N */
printf("This program will compute 5^N; enter N: ");
scanf("%u", &endCount);

printf("entered value = %d (as signed)\n",endCount);
printf("entered value = %u (as unsigned)\n",endCount);
```

On my system:

```
This program will compute 5^N; enter N: -10
entered value = -10 (as signed)
entered value = 4294967286 (as unsigned)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to only allow unsigned integers because then I would not be able to check if the user inputted a negative integer (unless I'm mistaken). The whole problem I have with this program is that I cannot really tell if the user inputs a number greater than 2^31-1 because it rolls over into negative integers. If I did not have this check in place, the program would always think they put in a negative integer when they really put in a really big positive integer. Also, be careful, endCount and endCountUn are not the same variables.

Comment: Also the strange thing is that this program runs exactly as it should (at least in my compiler). Any time you put in a negative integer or an integer greater that 2^31-1, the correct if statement executes.

Comment: Now I get curious which system and which compiler you use :)